# React Native with ScrollView feels sluggish

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview

Any idea why ScrollView + multiline TextInput + KeyboardAvoidingView feels really sluggish? I'm using react-navigation with the react-native-screen for the native modal look. The screenshot gif below is taken on emulator but it behave similarly even on the real device (notice that there is a flash of blue background just before keyboard showed up)

My code looks something like (I set the `KeyboardAvoidingView` background to pink so it's easy to spot and `ScrollView` background is set to blue

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'padding'} style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'pink'}} keyboardVerticalOffset={48}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text>{date}</Text>
            <Button title="Delete"/>
            <Button title="Save"/>
        </View>
        <ScrollView keyboardDismissMode={'interactive'} style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
            <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => setNote(text)}
                       placeholder='Note'
                       value={note}
                       multiline={true}
                       scrollEnabled={false}
                       style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}
            />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

I'm also using react-native-elements, react-navigation+react-native-screens for the native modal look

[image: screenshot]

PS - I tried not using ScrollView and simply using TextInput with `scrollable={true}` which seems to be working but the problem with that is I can't dismiss the keyboard once the keyboard is shown